# Get queries work only on Id column inside same transaction

Tags: transactions, spring-data, spring-data-gemfire

Consider a class Person which has 3 attributes { id ,name ,age }
The id is formed as name||age.
A get query is working only by Id (in the same transaction the record was created)

```
 @Transactional
public void test(String id,String id2 ) {
 personService.save(new Person("abc","123"));
 Person person = repository.findByNameAndAge("abc", "23"); //doesn't work in same transaction
    //however find by Id column works in same transaction works
    repository.findOne("abc||23") 
    }
```

From another transaction call 
`repository.findByNameAndAge("abc", "23")` returns result but in the same transaction in which that record is being created it doesn't return any result.

Here the repository is

```
 public interface PersonRepository extends GemfireRepository<RecordRevision, String> {
           List<Person> findByNameAndAge(String name, String age);
```

The regions are REPLICATE_PERSISTENT and I am using PDX serialization
The call should work even in the same transaction,Is this any known issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known limitation in GemFire [[1]]. The Query engine does not see the transaction state. A lookup by id is converted into a GemFire region.get() which is able to see the transactional state.

[1] http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/latest/developing/transactions/working_with_transactions.html#concept_ty1_vnt_vk